# isometries preserving probability measure for standard probability spaces or some other class of spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Is there a class of metric measure spaces for which a probability measure is preserved by an isometry? It is clear that for a generic metric measure space, isometries do not preserve measure. However, it intuitively makes sense to think that for instance, the Euclidean group preserves probability measure.

Is there a proof to show that either this is or is not the case? Moreover, if this is true, is there a larger class of metric measure spaces for which this is true?

I am new to this field so pardon the lack of rigor in asking the question.

Comment: Yes, you can find a probability measure on, say, the real line, which is invariant under all translations (since ${\mathbb R}$ is an amenable group). But this will not give you a metric-measure space structure. Would a m-m structure on a compact pace satisfy you?